# How to install ubiquity to Full install bootable USB

Tags: system-installation, usb, ubiquity

I have made a Full install bootable USB flash drive.

I would like to use it to install Ubuntu to a friends computer.

Can I install the Ubiquity installer to this flash drive?

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Ubiquity and that in turn will install all the lower level packages it needs to install Ubuntu to another drive.

```
sudo apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-gtk
```

Running it is a manner of running

```
ubiquity --desktop gtk_ui
```

The manpage is a bit inconsistent on this, but it looks like you *don't* run it as root, and it will call gksudo itself when necessary, but if that doesn't work try calling it with gksudo.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried these commands yesterday, install works but when I enter "ubiquity --desktop gtk_ui" , I get a password box but the installer does not appear. Terminal returns "Usage: ubiquity [options] [frontend]" - "ubiquity: error: no such option: --desktop". if I type "sudo ubiquity" the installer pops up. I will try again on a fresh install, but all seems good.

Comment: `--desktop` is supposedly unnecessary, just alters what's written on the password prompt.  *Don't* use `sudo`.  If anything, try with and without `gksudo` but not `sudo`.

Comment: If I do it with sudo terminal asks my password, if I do without sudo a window comes up and asks my password. I have been trying to install a Linux Live Kit remix iso to hard disk but ubiquity keeps failing before completion. I think the problem is in the remixing.