# Make Full Install to USB Able to Install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb, usb-installation, ubiquity

Have Live USBs for installing Ubuntu.

Have Full install USBs for regular use.

Would like to be able to use the Full install USBs as installers to eliminate the need for the Live USBs.

Installed Ubiquity to Full install USB per: [How to install ubiquity to Full install bootable USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995980/how-to-install-ubiquity-to-full-install-bootable-usb)

The installer seems to run fine up to the point of adding names and password, then it crashes.

Maybe Ubiquity can not find a package to install?

How can I make a Full install USB that can be used to install Ubuntu?

Can it be made to install various flavors of Buntu also?

Comment: I just add every ISO I want to boot into my USB drive and use grub2's loopmount to directly boot the ISO. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c path & boot parameters are my usual issues. I often have to look inside ISO to see grub's boot parameters.

Comment: @oldfred: I want to start with a Full install USB, (like to internal drive). So I can use full disc encryption, Nvidia graphic drivers, run software updates and upgrades, etc. Then I want to install Ubiquity so I can install Ubuntu to another computer when necessary. It crashes part way through each install attempt.

Comment: Maybe Ubiquity has a log somewhere to help you debug the issue?

Comment: @guillermo chamorro : The error report was over my head, I will look for a Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Install Ubuntu using Full install USB*

Nowadays USB drives are becoming large enough that having an extra ISO file is no big deal.

Place your Ubuntu ISO at the root of the USB.

Modify the USB's grub.cfg by adding this menuentry to /etc/grub.d/40_custom and running `sudo update-grub`:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu-18.04 64-bit ISO" {
    set root=(hd0,1)
    set isofile="/ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso"
        loopback loop $isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile splash --
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

(hd0,1) assumes root is sda1.

You will then have the option to boot the USB drive to a Live installer system.

*Ubuntu 19.10 and later use grub 2.04 which does not boot ISO files. To create a Full install that uses grub 2.02 see [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step) NOTE 1 Re: **mkusb usb-pack-efi option**.

Comment: @sudodus Yes, good point.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions to create a live Ubuntu disk: https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/

Just remember to leave a space of the USB stick to install the program you want.

Comment: Thank you for reply, however please see my comment to oldfred. I want a Full install to USB that can Install Ubuntu.