# Install fresh system on empty drive without rebooting?

Tags: system-installation, 20.10

I have Ubuntu 20.10 running.

But I want to make a fresh OS install on another drive.

Can I do this without rebooting on a USB drive? I need to minimize downtime.

So is there a tool I can grab for an existing system that can create another system on a spare drive?

In other words: install from a live system, instead of a live CD / USB ISO image?

Comment: Here is a possible solution:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/995980/how-to-install-ubiquity-to-full-install-bootable-usb  I have never tried it though, but it is running the actual Ubuntu installer that is ran from a LiveCD/DVD/USB environment.

Comment: You can install using an image file, it is just a matter of flashing an OS image to overwrite a blank disk using a tool like Rufus, Etcher or mkusb. For method see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300454/easy-full-install-usb-that-boots-both-bios-and-uefi .  No down time required at all. You can also install Ubuntu to a disk using VirtualBox.